# Can't seem to pass variable using select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I have a form in Rails that I need to create an option tag in HTML. It's a pretty simple option list with static values. I could create it in HTML easy enough, but I want to do it the "Rails Way"

Here is a portion of my form:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :area %><br />
        <%= select_tag "area", options_for_select([["Northeast", "NE"], ["Southeast", "SE"], ["Central", "CE"], ["West", "WE"], ]) %>

   </div>
   <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
```

When I use the select_tag, my form shows that it is successfully posting changes, but the value that is passed by the select_tag is not updated to the database. I have verified that a simple text field DOES pass the value.

I'm sure I'm missing something very simple, but I'm having a difficult time identifying it. Please help. Thanks!

Rails Newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select_tag` is like `text_field_tag`: it doesn't cooperate with the form builder (the object `form_for` yields) in order to get the proper parameter name and current value.

the `select` helper is ever so slightly different to `select_tag` in that it calls options for select for you, so you only need to write

```
f.select 'area', [["Notheast", "NE"], ...]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the specific information I needed. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

Check your rendering: a bare `select_tag` will render `"area"` as the name/id, whereas everything else in your form will have a normal model-based name.

For example, if the model was `"user"`, the phone field's name would be `"user[phone]"`.

You can see this happening by looking at your parameters passed to the action in the log.

Either use the form helper, or name it correctly the same as the other fields.

See also: [select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select), [select_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag), [select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/select) (not helpful), and [form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease). The ["Understanding Parameter Naming Conventions"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#understanding-parameter-naming-conventions) section might also be of interest.